# what is the decryption process for the TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider

Tags: encryption

when i am trying to crack a encryption and decryption application i found that they are using following.

https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B6UFLPrXUMm1TjVrYWFVR2t4cW8/edit?usp=sharing?

following code..

but i cant analyse the code.. could u plz help in preparing a decryption app for this encryption..

key = D8437A50-0FAC-47EB-A359-A0A196BA7783

encrypted data = K6NjWUyOat3LdF+ZUrftrLZgydkly64e+

plz this is my genune question.

```
   public static string Encrypt__(string toEncrypt, bool useHashing)
       {
           byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(toEncrypt);
           string key = Encrypt.getKey();
           string[] array = key.Split(new char[]
           {
               '-'
           });
           string s = key;
           byte[] key2;
           if (useHashing)
           {
               MD5CryptoServiceProvider mD5CryptoServiceProvider = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();
               key2 = mD5CryptoServiceProvider.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(array[1]));
               mD5CryptoServiceProvider.Clear();
           }
           else
           {
               key2 = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(s);
           }
           TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider tripleDESCryptoServiceProvider = new TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider
           {
               Key = key2, 
               Mode = CipherMode.ECB, 
               Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7
           };
           byte[] array2 = tripleDESCryptoServiceProvider.CreateEncryptor().TransformFinalBlock(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
           tripleDESCryptoServiceProvider.Clear();
           return array[0] + Convert.ToBase64String(array2, 0, array2.Length);
       }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Wikipedia: [TripleDES](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triple_DES) is the common name for the Triple Data Encryption Algorithm (TDEA or Triple DEA) block cipher, which applies the Data Encryption Standard (DES) cipher algorithm three times to each data block.

It is a standard encryption algorithm. The wikipedia article has a summary of the algorithm and links to full specification documents.